# How do I create a custom archive page depending on the custom taxonomy type?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I've created a custom taxonomy called 'productCategories' using [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function. I've set the rewrite slug to 'products'.

My question is: How do I render a different template to `archive.php` for my custom taxonomy /products ?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template file called `taxonomy-productCategories.php`. For more information, see the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). I find [this image](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aTemplate_Hierarchy.png) particularly helpful.